# Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular

I am using [urigo:angular2-meteor](https://github.com/Urigo/Meteor-Angular2/). When I add an empty main.ts in server folder, it always shows:

> Cannot compile namespaces when the '--isolatedModules' flag is
>   provided.

Even I added the code below on the top of main.ts, it still shows same thing.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2-meteor.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I faced similar issue in react + ts. I had commented out all my code.

Turns out
*A global file cannot be compiled using '--isolatedModules'. Ensure your file contains imports, exports, or an 'export {}' statement.*

So, added something like:

```
export const foo = 'foo';
```

or

```
export {}
```

It's a temporary solution, else you can delete the file with commented code or update **tsconfig.json**

Comment: In my case, I just had some empty files ready for stubbing out.

Comment: and what to update there in the `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: @PardeepJain the accepted answer is all about that only

Comment: You can do it without exporting anything: add "export {}" at the end of the file

Comment: Where should I place it??

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem and I added `tsconfig.json` into the root directory of my project.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "isolatedModules": false
    }
}
```

I didn't have the time to dive into it, but it solved the problem.

Comment: you won't get alerts if you have components you aren't using if you term this off... how much that matters is up to you!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error when file was not imported in any other file. 
Importing it in any other file (import {} from "/the-filename-having-compilation-error"), removed this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was made a component and never use that. When I imported that component In one of my page and use that and RERUN the project again , error was disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs mostly when working with React + TypeScript 
Simplest Solution for the same is to add 'export' keyword before the class creation or export the class in the end using

export default className;

Answer (score -2):

If you have eslint installed check the rules section in .eslintrc.json file for any  contradicting action.If the action you perforned is against the rule defined then error appears.